# How would I be able to use a file in visual studio project on any computer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, path, connection

I have a project that let's say loads a excel file to a string using this connection:

```
string PATH = @"C:\localfile\user\bob\firstcomputer\file.xlsx";
        string connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                             Data Source=" + PATH + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";
......... ..... ...blah blah blah loads excel to string ect.
```

I want to use this visual project on another computer without having to change the string path to match that computer's. Is there a way to reference that file so that using it on any computer will work without changing the path in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You would write a program that would ask for a location of a file before launching the application.  The only computer specific data I see in your code is the location of the file.  You might also add error checking to determine if it could find excel and the related OLEDB provider.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to store the file in a shared location (shared drive, for instance) that multiple computers are mapped to - this way, you wouldn't have to worry about changing the file path or mimicking the file structure on each computer.

Comment: Ok, so if i put it in a shared location, how would i reference the path?

Comment: it would be entered in the same exact way you have here, just with a consistent value. For instance, if you had a shared drive say Q: or something, it would be Q:\localfile\user\bob\firstcomputer\file.xlsx, and that value could stay consistent between computers instead of having to remake the file structure you were looking to avoid. For how-tos on mapping to shared drives, check this out:
http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows/create-shortcut-map-network-drive#1TC=windows-7. The only trade off here is that you would need to set up _that_ environment, but only once, and also save to Q:\.